# How to filter out "#N/A N/A" from Bloomberg data using the advanced filter in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a huge data file with stock price history downloaded from Bloomberg, which looks like this:

[image: 1]

I want to filter the data so that I only get the cells with actually prices in them - a lot of the cells have `#N/A N/A` in them if Bloomberg could not get pricing data.

I used the advanced filter by selecting the entire range, for criteria I put `<> "#N/A N/A"` but it's not working. Any advice on how to accomplish this task?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because questions must demonstrate a reasonable amount of research & understanding of the problem being solved. Please edit to either a) clearly describe your problem and the research done so far to solve it or b) include attempted solutions plus why they didn't work. In either case, be sure your expected results are clearly presented.

Comment: Hi Dmlawton, can you post a short snippet of the data with the "N/A N/A" as text? Or point us to the download? Currently it's hard to answer your question.
Also, it seems you're trying to use the advanced filter. Did you try searching the web for "how to use excel advanced filter"? It might point you in the right direction.

Comment: I added a link to an image of part of the data. It looks like that - I have 3000 stocks each with daily prices dating back to 1980. I want to filter it so that it removes the N/A's, because ultimately I want to compute the return of each stock from its start date to today @SaaruLindestøkke

Comment: What do you want to happen to the data? Do you want to remove the columns containing the #NA or delete the value from the cells? i.e. what are you expecting to see when you have run the filter? You should be able to enter a formula that ignores the NA values and sums the existing values if that is what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Given below example data (which contains the filter in the top 2 rows and the data from the 4th row onwards):

```
id   value
     <>#N/A N/A
    
id   value
1    2153
2    #N/A N/A
23   2231
8    454
4    N/A
56   #N/A N/A
6    56
67   0
```

[image]

You can use the following advanced filtering setup to filter out the `#N/A N/A` rows:

[image]

Resulting in:

[image]

Here's a GIF showing that, yes, the `<>#N/A N/A` condition actually filters the rows:

[image]

<sub>Credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43333719/1256347) for showing how to do exclusion conditions.</sub>

Comment: The criteria you are using `<>#N/A N/A` doesn't works, you need to use two cells side by side for criteria like `<>#N/A` and `<>N/A`. Please [edit] the post & correct the mistake to avoid negative votes,

Comment: Hi Rajesh, with the example data I posted the criteria works exactly as shown in the screenshot. The condition `<>#N/A N/A` leaves out cells that contain *the string* `#N/A N/A`. From the question I understand that's the cell values the OP wants to filter. Can you indicate what's not working? Please note that we're not trying to filter the value `#N/A` here (indicating data which is not available), but the exact string `#N/A N/A`.

Comment: Not possible, if U use `<>#N/A N/A` as criteria in ONE CELL ,, then Excel will return all records ! In `B9` you have `N/A` and how any Excel formula could return error like `#N/A N/A `

Comment: @RajeshS I'm not sure I follow. [Here's a GIF of the process](https://imgur.com/QF2fH8Z). I've put `<>#N/A N/A` in ONE CELL, Excel did not return all records. It left out the rows that had `#N/A N/A` in it, i.e. row 6 and 10 are hidden.

Comment: @RajeshS please (re-)read the question. The question asker wants to filter `#N/A N/A`. They do not mention anything about wanting to filter `N/A`. I just put it there as dummy data. Excel cannot return an error like `#N/A N/A`, but the question is not about filtering Excel errors, it's about filtering the values shown in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Since you say you have a huge file and the rows with the bloomberg error values are not useful, you can avoid thousands of rows with formulas and remove the error rows entirely. Instead of Advanced Filter, I recommend you use Power Query for this.

Select any cell in your data, then use Data>Get & Transform Data>From Table/Range

This will open the Power Query Editor.

In the Power Query Editor, right click one of the error values and select Filters>Does Not Equal:

[image]

This will filter out all rows in that dataset with that value in that column. Repeat as necessary for other columns then click Home>Close & Load to put the data back into the workbook on a new sheet which you can now use for further calculation, Pivot Tables, or whatever you need.